# になっている vs がある ？

Tags: grammar

I found a sentence from my study book.

It said:

> このマンションは動物を飼ってはいけない規則になっている

Why is it

> になっている

and not

> がある ?

Is it replaceable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question, I think that it would be good to review the V + ている conjugation.

A lot of the time we are taught that V + ている means "verb-ing."  For many cases that is correct.  However, there are some cases where "verb-ing" is not 100% accurate as far as translation goes.  For example, 死{し}んでいる does not mean `dying`, but `dead`.

In my time in Japan, I spent a bit of time going door to door as part of my work.  Quite often, the person answering the door would say:

> 主人{しゅじん}は仕事{しごと}に行{い}っています。

In the morning, translating this as `My husband is going to work` would make sense, but it doesn't make as much sense at 4:00PM.  This is because translating 行{い}っている as `going` isn't correct.  Rather, you should translate it as `has gone to __` or `is at __`.  Long story short, you would translate it as:

> My husband is at work.

For more information, please see [this](http://www.punipunijapan.com/japanese-te-iru/) webpage.  I really like how it describes the meaning of V + ている in terms of resultant states.  We are dealing with a resultant state in this situation.  To use their words:

> If the verb indicates an instantaneous change of state or transfer, then the て- form + いる (iru) will express a resultant state.

Like 行{い}っている (has gone to/is at) or 死{し}んでいる (is dead)。

---

Become (なる) is another one of those cases.  You cannot translate it as becoming, as that would not be correct, but rather translate it as `it is established` or `it is the case that.`

> このマンションは動物{どうぶつ}を飼{か}ってはいけない規則{きそく}になっている
>
> It has been established that keeping pets at this mansion is not allowed.

Why not ～がある？ Well, in terms of overall meaning you *could* replace ～になっている with ～がある、and have it carry *almost* the same meaning (I wouldn't do it though).  This is not just a question of style/formality, but also a question of meaning.  It's not as formal to say ～がある, and it means something different.

Just to be clear, this does not mean ～がある ＝ ～になっている。That is false, as *the meanings are different*.  It just happens to be the case that you *could* rephrase the sentence with ～がある and carry a similar meaning.  Here is an example to drive this point home:

> わが家{や}では、お箸{はし}を使{つか}わず、手{て}で食{た}べることになっている。
>
> In our home, we don't use chopsticks, we eat with our hands.

Setting aside the peculiarity of this sentence, if we were to replace ～になっている with ～がある、we would have a different sentence.  Eating with your hands in that home is an established thing.  When I say established, I mean that things are always that way.  It's a tradition, not a one-time deal.

If we were to say:

> わが家{や}では、お箸{はし}を使{つか}わず、手{て}で食{た}べることがある。
>
> In our home, there are times when we don't use chopsticks and eat with our hands.

There is no sense of establishment.  This isn't a tradition, it's more of a fling.

---

So, bringing it all together, the reason they use ～になっている in your sentence is because the rule (規則{きそく}) is established.  It's not just a thing that happens.  There is a sense of permanence and there is an expectation that you will abide by that rule.

If you were to say ～がある、you would get the feeling that there's a rule that pets aren't allowed, but not everyone follows the rules.  So while you would get *almost* the same meaning, they are in fact different.

Comment: It might be a lot to ask, but could you go back through and add some furigana? I can see this being an often referenced and or popular question and answer to visit. Might as well make it more accessible to those learning ;) (like me). Anyway, great answer, and thank you!

Comment: What'd be the meaning if I used です in place of になっている？

Comment: @PawełBatko, You'd end up with a grammatically incorrect sentence.  わが家やでは、お箸はしを使つかわず、手てで食たべる...です。You already have a verb ending the sentence.  Now if we ended at that last verb (食べる), you would get none of the nuance I described previously, and just a statement of fact.

Comment: If that doesn't fully answer your question, I would suggest you ask it as a general question on the site, because I might have to get a little more involved in the explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ajsmart though I implicitly had this sentence in mind: `このマンションは動物を飼ってはいけない規則になっている`

Comment: @PawełBatko   `このマンションは動物を飼ってはいけない` is a phrase that modifies the noun 規則.  As such, you have `noun + です`, which isn't strictly speaking a complete sentence.  It can be a response to a question like `どんな規則ですか` (what type of rule?), to which you respond `it is a rule that says you can't keep pets.`  Does that make sense, or do I need to do more explaining?

Comment: I'm running out of characters in the comments, so...