# ている: 上がっています Context and Resultive State?

Tags: て-form

> また石油の値段が上がっています。

I have problems comprehending the use of ている in this context. To my understanding, 上がっています used in the example sentence is referring to the state of the "increased" price of 石油 (oil) and not the continuous action of in the process of going up. Am I right to say that?

I read a few past questions about てーいる and found out that it can also refer to a completed state. Can I assume it is referring to that in my example?

Answer (score 1):

> I read a few past questions about てーいる and found out that it can also refer to a completed state. Can I assume it is referring to that in my example?

With the context that has been given, it's unclear whether or not this is referring to a state of being raised (it's finished growing), or if it is still getting higher.  Context matters in situations where both can apply.  Without further context given, I would actually suspect that this case refers to the price being up (completed to this point).  That of course can change with the surrounding context.

Regardless of whether or not it is or isn't currently in the state of increasing, I would say that the translation into English will usually say `the price of oil is up,` and the state of whether it is currently increasing/decreasing would not matter.

In regards to the completed state of being, yes.  I wrote an [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/51701/22352) about this state previously that I feel explains the completed state fairly well.

I'm going to pose a few hypothetical situations so that you can see how the context will change what is being said in your phrase.

Scenario 1:  It's the morning, and the stock exchanges have just opened.  Person A comments that the price of Gold is increasing, to which person B replies with the phrase: `また石油の値段が上がっています。`  I would translate this as something to the effect of `Additionally, the price of oil is increasing.`  The price is in the state of growing.

Scenario 2:  It's the evening, and the stock exchanges have just closed.  Person A comments: `今日、金の値段が高くなりましたね。` (The price of gold got expensive today.) Person B says: `また石油の値段が上がっています。`  This is the same phrase, but I would actually take it to mean: `Additionally, the price of oil is up.`  The price growth has completed.

Scenario 3:  Yesterday the price of oil increased, and today you check again.  When you see that the price of oil is up, you say: `また石油の値段が上がっています。`  Here I'd translate this as: `Again, the price of oil is/has increas(ing/ed).`  This will depend on whether or not the expectations of the speaker, whether the markets are closed, and other variables.  Either way, the price growth could be in either state without more context.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would like to clarify what you meant by "and the state of whether it is currently increasing/decreasing would not matter"?